# Prove that the sequence $x_n=\frac{n}{1+\frac{1}{n}}$ is divergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

My attempt:I was trying to prove by the method of contradiction . I suppose that $x_n$ is convergent then $lim(x_n)=L$ where $L$ is not infinity. Now $lim(x_n).lim(1+\frac{1}{n}) = lim(n)$. Now $lim(1+\frac{1}{n})= 1 $ .Thus $lim(n)=L$.hence we arrive at a contradiction . Am I correct?

Comment: $$x_n=\frac{n^2}{n+1}\geq\frac{n^2}{2n}=\frac{n}{2}$$ which diverges

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy I assume you are talking about my attempt then can I  use the same method to prove that $x_n =\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n+1}$is divergent?

Comment: @smita I though you again had $1+\frac 1 n$ in the denominator. I have deleted my previous comment. If the denominator is $1+n$ then the sequence is convergent.

Comment: @smita No, because it converges

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was $x_n= \frac{n(-1)^{n}}{n+1}$

Comment: I wasn't able to edit it .. Now I assume that the sequence diverges and can I use the same attempt that I have used above in my answer?

Comment: @smita, for your last sequence, look at the subsequences $(x_{2n})$ and $(x_{2n+1})$ and calculate their limits.

Comment: What will be wrong if I assume that $x_n=L$ and$ lim((-1)^n)= L*1$ which is a contradiction..

Comment: smita, and why doesn't $(-1)^n$ have a limit?

Comment: It is because it is divergent ...

Comment: smita, doesn't have a limit and divergent means the same thing, I asked why is it so?